# Can I use BindingHandler.applyBindings and Docx4j.bind together?

Tags: binding, docx4j

I know using both to apply the bindings is unconventional. But in my case, some values come from the database and I will set them in the code, use BindingHandler to bind them. Some other values will mostly be static and will be available in an xml file. In that case, use Docx4j.bind. I tried this and only Docx4j.bind will work even if I call them both in different orders.

Any thoughts on how I can use both and still let the bindings stay?

Answer (score 1):

As things stand, the simplest approach would be to create an XML file combining both your existing XML data, plus the values from the database.